# Why would one use "movl $1, %eax" as opposed to, say, "movb $1, %eax"

Tags: assembly, x86, att

As the title states, why would one use "movl $1, %eax" as opposed to, say, "movb $1, %eax", I was told that movl would zero out the high order bits of %eax, but isn't %eax a register that's equivalent to the size of the system's wordsize? meaning that movl is in actuality an integer operation (and not a long?)

I'm clearly a bit confused about it all; Thanks.

Comment: related: [Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](//stackoverflow.com/q/41573502)

Answer (score 45):

> opposed to, say, "movb $1, %eax"

This instruction is invalid.  You can't use eax with the movb instruction.
You would instead use an 8-bit register, or write [the full register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191178/how-do-ax-ah-al-map-onto-eax) with a value that has the value you want in the low byte(s) you care about.  For example:

```
movb  $1, %al        # AL = 1, merged with existing 3/7 bytes of previous EAX/RAX
movl  $1, %eax       # AL = 1, AX = 1, EAX = 1, RAX = 1
```

> but isn't %eax a register that's
> equivalent to the size of the system's
> wordsize?

No. EAX will always be a 32-bit value, regardless of what mode you're in.

You are confusing C variable sizes with register sizes.  C variable sizes may change depending on your system and compiler.

Assembly is simpler than C.  In GAS [AT&T](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info) assembly, instructions are suffixed with the letters "b", "s", "w", "l", "q" or "t" to determine what size operand is being manipulated.  (Or a register operand can imply a size, like `mov $1, %eax` implies `movl`, unlike with `mov $1, (%rdi)` which is ambiguous.

- `b` = byte (8 bit)
- `s` = single (32-bit floating point) used only for x87 instructions like `flds (mem)`
- `w` = word (16 bit)
- `l` = long (32 bit doubleword integer), or x87 64-bit floating point
- `q` = quad-word (64 bit)
- `t` = ten bytes (80-bit floating point)

These sizes are constant.  They will never be changed.  al is always 8-bits and eax is always 32-bits.

A "word" is always 16 bits in x86 terminology, and in modern x86 is unrelated to the concept of CPU or machine word size; [x86 isn't a word-oriented architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68229585/are-machine-code-instructions-fetched-in-little-endian-4-byte-words-on-an-intel).

Answer (score 7):

`%eax` is a 32-bit register. To use a smaller width, you need `%ax` for 16-bits. `%ax` can be further divided into `%ah` for the high byte of `%ax`, and `%al` for the lower byte. The same goes for the other x86 GPRs.

Looking at the Intel instruction set reference for the `mov` instruction, I don't see a variant that can move a single byte into a 32-bit register -- it's probably interpreted as a move into `%al`.

Since `movl` is a 32-bit instruction, the values for the upper bytes will correspond to zeros *in the case of an immediate value*. If you were moving from memory you would be moving an entire 32-bit word.

`%eax` is not zeroed out unless you either `movl $0, %eax`, or if you `xorl %eax, %eax`. Otherwise it holds whatever value was previously in there. When you `movl $1, %eax`, you will end up with `0x00000001` in the register because the 32-bit instruction moves a 32-bit immediate value into the register.

Comment: That movl is a 32 bit instruction is partly the answer I was looking for, but another answer I'm asking for is whether or not %eax by default is _not_ zeroed out, or is undefied?

Comment: %eax is never zeroed out unless you explicitly do so.  If you use movb to just write into one of the bytes, the other bytes are unchanged.

Comment: @NegativeAcknowledgement  [How do AX, AH, AL map onto EAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15191178) explains how partial-register writes affect the full register.  (Only writing a 32-bit register implicitly zero-extends to the full 64-bit.  Otherwise it just merges a new part of the register with the old 386 / 8086 semantics.)

Answer (score 7):

On a 32 bit machine, %eax is a 4 byte (32 bit) register.  movl will write into all 4 bytes.  In your example, it'll zero out the upper 3 bytes, and put 1 in the lowest byte.  The movb will just change the low order byte.

Comment: So movl is a 4 byte operation?

Comment: Not sure which assembler this is, but isn't the only difference the size of the constant?

Comment: Yes.  In the IA32 architecture (usually called x86), "long" means 4 bytes, and movl stands for "move long".

Comment: @Negative Acknowledgement: You're asking the wrong question. Every operation on a system is in multiples of the word size. On a 32-bit system, every operation works on 32 bits. The way the shorter (`movb`) instruction works is by AND'ing the first byte then adding your value, thus it is slow. You generally always want to work on full words or you'll incur speed penalties (at the cost of more memory used, of course).

Answer (score 4):

`long` was originally 32 bits, while `int` and `short` were 16. And the names of the opcodes don't change every time someone comes out with a new operating system.

Comment: What has a release of an operating system got to do with the naming conventions of types?

Comment: It was a figure of speech. The intent was to indicate that once published, the instruction set specification isn't destructively changed.

Comment: This is why I prefer Intel syntax to GAS syntax.  
Intel: mov dword eax, ecx
GAS: movl eax, ecx

The "l" size operand confuses people.  More people get that 'dword' means 32-bits.

Comment: Looks all the same to me, a dword (double word) suggests that the word size is 16 bits...

Comment: The word size *was* 16 bits on the 8086.

Comment: Uh, isn't x86 equivalent to 8086? isn't this what we're dealing with, and isn't it a 32 bit architecture?

Comment: The 8086 processor was quite definitively 16-bit.

Comment: @NegativeAcknowledgement: In Intel documentation / terminology, "word" means 16-bit.  Always and forever.  Not depending on what mode you're running in.  This is quirky and "exposes" x86-64's 16-bit heritage, but so what?  Now we have names for all power of 2 sizes.  SIMD instruction names are easy to understand/remember, like [`packssdw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/packsswb:packssdw) (pack with signed saturation from dword to word elements).  ISAs that started as 32-bit (like MIPS and ARM), often use `h` = half-word, e.g. MIPS `lhu` load half-word with zero-extension.

Answer (score 3):

Your second choice will just produce an error, x86 doesn't have that instruction. X86 is a bit unique with respect to loading bytes into certain registers. Yes, on most instruction set architectures the operand is zero or sign-extended, but x86 allows you to write just the lower byte or lower 16 bits of some of them.

There are certainly other choices, like clearing the register and then incrementing it, but here are three initially reasonable-looking choices you have:

```
   0:   b8 01 00 00 00          movl   $0x1,%eax

   5:   31 c0                   xorl   %eax,%eax
   7:   b0 01                   movb   $0x1,%al

   9:   b0 01                   movb   $0x1,%al
   b:   0f b6 c0                movzbl %al,%eax
```

The first is 5 bytes, the second 4, the third 5. So the second is the best choice if optimizing for space, otherwise I suppose the one most likely to run fast is the first one. X86 is deeply pipelined these days, so the two instructions will interlock and the machine may need quite a few wait states depending on details of the pipeline hardware.

Of course, these x86 ops are being translated in CPU-specific ways into ***[CPU micro-ops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro-operation),*** and so who knows what will happen.

Comment: For future reference, if you're optimizing for code-size you'd use xor-zero (2 bytes) + `inc %eax` (1 byte in 32-bit mode).  Or `push imm8` / `pop r32` or `pop r64`.  Or `lea reg, [reg+disp8]` from another reg with a known value. 
 [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132985). For speed, only the `lea` is worth considering, otherwise use `mov` with a 32-bit immediate.

Answer (score 2):

`%eax` is 32 bits on 32-bit machines. `%ax` is 16 bits, and `%ah` and `%al` are its 8-bit high and low constituents.

Therefore `movl` is perfectly valid here. Efficiency-wise, `movl` will be as fast as `movb`, and zeroing out the high 3 bytes of `%eax` is often a desirable property. You might want to use it as a 32-bit value later, so `movb` isn't a good way to move a byte there.