# Clarify subsections of 32-bit registers x86

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, cpu-registers

I have a question regarding the subsections of the 32-bit registers in x86 assembly: Are the lower subsections of a register (when used) treated like a part of the corresponding 32-bit register?

```
ror cl,2    
ror cl,2
push ecx
pop eax
```

Take for example the code section above - since `CL` is a subsection of the `ECX` register, when I push the contents of the register onto the stack does what was in the `CL` subsection get pushed onto the stack as well? Or are they treated separately?

And suppose if I then popped the stack onto the `EAX` register does what was in the `CL` register from before go into the `EAX` register?

Comment: `CL` is just a convenient way to access a few bits of `ECX`, they are the same register.

Comment: Pushing ECX will push the 8 bits in CL as well.  Popping it into EAX will copy those 8 bits into AL.

Comment: @Linuxios & Hans Passant - okay cheers fellas I see what you mean. Much appreciated

Comment: You could read your CPU manual (downloadable for free from intel.com or amd.com).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ECX` register contains `CX` in its lower part, which contains `CH` and `CL` as represented in the  picture below. When modifying the value stored in `CL`, you also change `CX` and `ECX`, but not `CH`.

**To answer your questions:**

**Q:** *When I push the contents of the register [`ECX`] onto the stack does what was in the `CL` subsection get pushed onto the stack as well? Or are they  treated seperatley?*.
**A:** All in one shot. `CL` is part of `ECX`. `CL` is just a way provided by the processor to access a part of `ECX`.

**Q:** *And suppose if I then poped the stack onto the `EAX` register does what was in the `CL` register from before go into the `EAX` register?*.
**A:** Yes. More precisely, what was in `CL` would go into `AL`.

[image: x86-32 register board]

***Source:** [A tutorial on Register Allocation by Puzzle Solving](http://compilers.cs.ucla.edu/fernando/projects/puzzles/tutorial/) (on compilers.cs.ucla.edu)*

Comment: See also [How do AX, AH, AL map onto EAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15191178) for various ASCII-art diagrams and explanations in words, including the semantics for writing partial registers.