# Assembly - How to move content of eax (32bit) to a 16bit array?

Tags: assembly, x86

It doesn't necessarily have to be an array (it can be a register such as ax).

It's part of an exercise and it recommends to move only the first (right) 16 bit of eax to the array.

Comment: Since the low 16 bits are already in `ax`, you are done :) But if you want to `mov` it to anywhere else, just do so.

Comment: `ax` already contains the lower 16 bits of `eax`, since `ax` is just another "subview" of the `a` register. See my answer here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37275984/revisions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [x86 Calculating AX given AH and AL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37243801/x86-calculating-ax-given-ah-and-al) (because CherryDT's answer has a nice ASCII-art register subset diagram).

Comment: See also the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Answer (score 4):

The Intel registers can be referred to in a number of ways depending on how many bits you need:

- RAX - 64 bits
- EAX - The lower (rightmost) 32 bits of RAX
- AX  - The lower (rightmost) 16 bits of EAX
- AH  - The top 8 bits of AX
- AL  - The lower 8 bits of AX

To grab the lower 16 bits of EAX you could simply:

```
MOV BX, AX
```