# Assembly bit memory limit in arithmetic

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, masm, irvine32

I wanted to add the following numbers: 40, 90, 50 and 155 and I get a total of 355.

I wanted to experiment and test out whether the register AL will have a bit limit of (2^8) - 1, and when I compiled the code and execute the code, I get decimal of 1376331855. How did that happen?

Also, I thought 355 is greater than 255, and as a result should display an overflow exception.

I understand if I use MOVZX I will be able to carry the calculation into the higher register of AX.

Also, I am very confused with the difference between AL and AH. Is there a different in memory allocation for AL and AH?

```
TITLE Adding              
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.code
main PROC

    mov al,0h             ; 
    add al,28h            ; 40

    add al,5Ah            ; 90 
    add al,32h            ;50
    add al,9Bh            ;155
                            ; total is 355
    call DumpRegs
    call writedec

exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Replace `mov al,0h` by `mov ax,0h` or by `mov eax,0h`. I think the Irvine library uses EAX.

Comment: I understand why you would do that, but I am curious about the value resulted from using register AL. Why is it that value and not an overflow error? Thank you.

Comment: It's possible that the overflow is happening but you are not checking for it.

Comment: So in the command line, when an overflow happens, it will never tell you, but instead an obscure number is the result? Thanks

Comment: Assembly has mysterious ways. You can check for the overflow using the jxx instructions (JO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, DumpRegs gives you the output of EAX. When I convert your answer to HEX, I get 5209284F, the 4F being in the AL. 4F HEX is 79 Decimal, which is 335 - 256. The AL register only holds 8 bits, so 256 is the maximum unsigned integer it can hold.

Clear EAX before you begin and the results may make more sense.

Comment: Yup, exactly what I expected and said in my answer.  But +1 for showing the OP that the low byte really did hold the expected value.

Comment: 255 is the maximum. It can hold 256 values, but since 0 is also a value, 255 is the highest.

Answer (score 3):

> Also, I am very confused with the difference between AL and AH. Is there a different in memory allocation for AL and AH?

No, there's no memory involved.  They're both byte registers within EAX.

- AX is the low 16 bits of EAX
- AH and AL are the high and low halves of AX

See also [this ascii-art diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37243801/x86-calculating-ax-given-ah-and-al/37275984#37275984).  Or in C:

```
union eax {
    uint32_t EAX;                // regs aren't really signed or unsigned, but they have well-defined wraparound semantics like C unsigned (and unlike C signed).
    uint16_t AX;
    struct { uint8_t AL, AH; };  // anonymous struct, in little-endian order (AL is the low byte).
};
```

**Writes to any member are reflected in the values of other members**, but don't zero the rest of the register.  (footnote1)

---

Your print function prints all of EAX, but you never zeroed the high bytes of EAX before printing it.  **On entry to `main`, you need to assume that all bytes of EAX are random garbage**.

```
main PROC

    xor    eax, eax       ; zero eax
    ; mov al,0h      ; instead of just zeroing al and leaving garbage in the upper 24 bits
    add    al,28h         ; then play around with the low byte if you want
    ...
    add    al,9Bh         ; AL wraps around, but no carry happens into the rest of EAX.
    ;  If you want that, use a wider register:
    ; add   eax, 9Bh

    call writedec         ; prints eax as a signed integer
```

---

> I thought 355 is greater than 255, and as a result should display an overflow exception.

Integer overflow sets flags, which you can test later.  **See [Understanding Carry vs. Overflow conditions/flags](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt)**

It doesn't trigger faults / exceptions.  (Except for division)

---

(1): Strict ISO C90, and ISO C++, actually don't allow reading a union member that wasn't the last one written (undefined behaviour).  [ISO C99, (and GNU C++ as an extension) do guarantee type-punning with unions works as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25672839/224132).