# x86 partial registers (EAX, AX, AH) being set from data in memory

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

In the assembly programming I understand:

```
EAX : 22 66 77 55
 AX :       77 55
 AH :       77
 AL :          55
```

But I don't really understand how it works when reading data from an array with pointer offsets:

```
 .data 
 arrayW WORD 1233h,2245h, 1176h

 ptr2 PWORD arrayW

 .code 
    mov esi, ptr2
    mov ax, [esi]
    mov ah, [esi + 1]
    mov ax, [esi + 2]
    mov eax, [esi + 2]
```

**mov ax, [esi]** the register EAX = 12331233. I thought the register EAX would be 00001233?

Also, **mov ax, [esi + 2]** the register = EAX = 12334455. I don't understand how the register became 12334455.

Can someone please explain to me what all the values of the registers will be after the execution?

Comment: Related: [Assembly language - Why are characters stored in register as little endian?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48645360)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Assembly programming memory Allocating EAX vs Ax, AH, AL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191178/assembly-programming-memory-allocating-eax-vs-ax-ah-al) for how AX, AH, and AL overlap, as subsets of EAX.

Writing partial registers (AX, AH, or AL) doesn't modify the rest of EAX.  (In 64-bit mode, [writing EAX *does* zero the upper half of RAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register))

So `mov ax, [esi]` leaves the top 2 bytes of EAX unmodified, and replaces the low 2 bytes with AX=0x1233.  That means AH=0x12 and AL=0x33, and EAX=`0x22 66 12 33`.

---

Bytes in memory are little endian, so `mov ah, [esi + 1]` loads 0x12 (the upper byte of `0x1233`, the first word of the array.)

This is assembly language.  Everything is just bytes.  It doesn't matter that they got there in that order because you used `WORD 1233h,2245h` instead of `BYTE 33h,12h, 45h, 22h`.  The CPU doesn't know or care about any "meaning" for the instruction, it just loads 1 byte from `[esi+1]`, and puts it in AH.  (Which already had that value from `mov ax, [esi]`).

Bytes in registers don't have an endianness, since they don't have addresses.  Left shifts always multiply by 2, right shifts always divide by 2 (rounding towards -Infinity, unlike signed integer division).

---

See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for more FAQ questions, and links to docs and guides.

You can always put this code into a program and run it in a debugger to watch register values change as you single-step through it.  If you're not sure what happens, do that.

---

BTW, `mov esi, ptr2` is silly.  `mov esi, offset arrayW` would do the same thing without needing to load a pointer from data memory.

Comment: 'mov ah, [esi+1]' after the execution does the register's value change? Because it is WORD so [esi+1] doesn't point to anything right? [esi+2] points to the second element?

Comment: @student001: this is assembly language.  Everything is just bytes.  It doesn't matter that they got there in that order because you used `WORD 1233h,2245h` instead of `BYTE 33h,12h, 45h, 22h`.  The CPU doesn't know or care about any "meaning" for the instruction, it just loads 1 byte from `[esi+1]`.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this. But I just want to make sure I understand. So if I use `DWORD 12344h` = `BYTE 44h, 23h, 01h` . Is that right? And one more, `BYTE 1,2,3,4` = `WORD 4321h` ?

Comment: @student001: yes, but you left out the 4th byte (`00h`).  a DWORD is always 4 bytes, and doesn't depend on the size of the constant.  (It stands for DoubleWord).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness has some pictures.