# NASM x86 print integer using extern printf

Tags: c, x86, nasm

I try to print an integer using printf in x86 assembly. For the format string `printf(fmtstring, vals)` i have stored the `%d` as fmtd. Then i put 1 into ax, 2 into bx, add them and want to print the result using call printf. Here is the code.

```
global _main

extern _printf

section .data
    fmtd db "%d"

section .text

_main:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

_begin:
    mov ax, 1
    mov bx, 2
    add ax, bx
    push ax
    push fmtd
    call _printf
    add esp, 8

_end:
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

but i get

```
-10485757
```

instead of expected

```
3
```

can you help me whats wrong with it?

When i just write

```
push 3
push fmtd
call _printf
```

it works as usual and prints 3.

Thank you

Comment: If you're doing 32 bit, shouldn't that be `mov eax,1`, `mov ebx,2`, etc?

Comment: Cant i just put a 1 into 16 bit so that it looks like `00000000 00000001` with the one on the right outer side? Is it in my case `10000000 00000000` or `10000000 20000000`?

Comment: ...and don't forget `push  eax` instead of `push  ax`.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking in your comment. In your code, you're trying to print 3 from the registers. You `push ax` which pushes 16 bit register (2 bytes) then `push fmtd` which pushes a 4 byte address. You need to push a 4 byte value for the `%d`, which would be `push eax`. To be clear on the whole sequence: `mov eax,1`, `mov ebx,2`, `add eax, ebx`, `push eax` then call `printf`.

Comment: `-10485757` is `FF600003` in hexadecimal. Does that ring a bell?

Comment: When i `mov ax 1 mov bx 2` is it the same as when i `mov eax 12`?

Comment: sorry i changed store to mov, it was a mistake

Comment: @Rajana of course not, what makes you think it's the same? `eax` is not related to `bx` at all, you should read your documentation again. BTW that's another question. Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191178/how-do-ax-ah-al-map-onto-eax. Google is your friend

Comment: @Rajana, `mov ax, 1` and `mov bx 2` is not at all the same as `mov eax, 12`. `bx` is not connected to `ax` or `eax`. They are completely separate registers.

Comment: I was about to say how does this not crash after you push 6 bytes and the `add esp,8`, but your stack-frame cleanup saved you with `mov esp,ebp`.  Although note that the low 2 bytes of your return address was below ESP for a couple instructions, and thus your code was at least theoretically unsafe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the full 32 bit registers:

You want this:

```
mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 2
add eax, ebx
push eax
push fmtd
call _printf
```

Explanation of output `-10485757` you get:

`-10485757` in hexadecimal is `FF600003`. The `0003` comes from the `push ax` which pushes the 16 low bits of `eax`. The `FF60` is whatever leftover was on the stack.

Reads [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191178/how-do-ax-ah-al-map-onto-eax) for detailed explanation about the relationship between `ax` and `eax`.