# <Assemble Language> May I know why inc al = FF00h

Tags: assembly, x86

the orginally is

mov ax, 0FFFFh; <---  in this mov 0FFFFh = -1, I get it

inc ax, 0FFFFh; <--- bc increment by 1, so is 0, it will become 0000h, I get it

---

can someone help me to explain why the answer is FF00h for this variation?

```
mov ax, 0FFFFh;
inc al;
```

Answer (score 1):

`al` is the low 8 bits of `ax`.  8-bit instructions that use `al` as an operand only operate on those 8 bits.  In particular, as you see, carries out of `al` do not affect anything else.

See [How do AX, AH, AL map onto EAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191178/how-do-ax-ah-al-map-onto-eax)

Comment: Looks like just a duplicate.  Last month I edited the top answer on that linked question to add the fact that "Writing AL, AH, or AX merges into the full AX/EAX/RAX", making it a good dup target for questions like this.

Comment: I do understand AL is lower part of AX, so, I wonder the anwser is 00FFh not FF00h

Comment: @Linux The answer *is* `FF00h`: `AL` is incremented and wraps around from `FFh` to `00h`, and `AH` is unchanged at `FFh`.  Note that the "low", i.e. least-significant bits are written on the right. So for instance when `AX = 1234h`, you have `AH = 12h` and `AL = 34h`. You'd get `00FF` if you did `inc ah`.

Comment: @Linux: Maybe you're confused that x86 is little-endian and so the least-significant byte occupies the lowest address in memory?  But AX is a register, not memory.  Even in memory, when talking about words instead of their individual bytes, we continue to write them in usual numerical notation with the least-significant bits on the right.

Comment: yes, I still confusing with the mapping

Comment: because if I perform "mov ax 1234h" "sub al 35h" I will get 12FFh, and because didn't borrow from ah, so the 12 didn't change, but if I "sub ax 35h", it will become 11FFh

Comment: @Linux: Yes, exactly.  When you operate on AX you are doing 16-bit operations, and you will get carries/borrows from the low half to the high half.