# Accessing "array" data in GNU assembler using Intel syntax

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, intel-syntax

I am tasked to write a GNU assembly program using Intel syntax which counts numbers in array which are <= 6 
I came up with the following code:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.data
    n: .word 5
    a: .word 1, 6, 7, 4, 8
    r: .word 0

.text
.global main
main:

    mov cx, n
    mov al, 0

    mov eax, 0
            
l1: cmpw [a+eax*2], 6
    ja l2
    inc al
l2: inc eax
    loop l1
    
    mov r, al
    ret
```

However while debugging it with GDB it seems to output 8 to variable `r` which is incorrect for given data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do AX, AH, AL map onto EAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191178/how-do-ax-ah-al-map-onto-eax)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think `al` and `eax` are two independent registers, but actually, `al` is just the lowest byte of `eax`, so you were using the same register for two different things at the same time. Use another register like `edx` as your array index instead of `eax`.

Also, you're almost certainly not running in 16-bit mode, so `loop` won't just check `cx`, so the high bits of it will make the loop run more times than you want. Do `mov ecx, n` instead and also `.long 5` instead of `.word 5`.  (Or you could use `loopw l1` instead of `loop l1` if you're on 32-bit and really want to stick with just `cx` for some reason.)

Comment: 16-bit mode (on a 386 or later) allows 32-bit operand-size and address-size, the same way 32-bit mode allows 16-bit operand-size and address-size.  But using GAS and  GDB with a `main:` that can `ret` is vastly more likely to be 32-bit mode under a modern OS like GNU/Linux, not 16-bit code, so yes, the ultimate point is correct, use ECX.  (And prefer `n=5` as an assemble-time constant; there's no reason to have `5` as a word or dword in memory in the .data section, an immediate would work fine.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Doesn't the `LOOP` instruction only care about the address size, though? Or do you mean it's legal to use `eax` in 16-bit code?

Comment: Yes, so if you assembled this code for 16-bit mode, `cmpw [a+eax*2], 6` would use an address-size override (`0x67`) to allow a 32-bit addressing mode (instead of a `0x66` for 16-bit operand-size in 32-bit mode).  And `loop` without an `addr32` override would use CX like this code is expecting.  Try it with `.code16` at the top of the file if you're curious.  (And the terrible way to fix this code for 32-bit mode would be `addr16 loop l1`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Huh, I didn't know 16-bit supported that. Also, it looks like `loopw` works as an alternative to `addr16 loop`.

Comment: Yeah, when 386 was new, Intel a lot of their CPUs would get used in 16-bit real mode most of the time, so new features usable in the existing mode would be useful.  And there was enough coding-space left at that point to introduce 2 prefix bytes into the existing mode.  Unlike when amd64 was new and they needed to repurpose some existing encodings since 32-bit mode had no unused single bytes for the start of an instruction.