# What value will RAX have after an 8-bit DIV instruction, with instructions that set up AL/AH and CL?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-registers

What is the correct answer? I've got this question on a test... :/

x86-64 architecture:

```
//What value will the register RAX have after
//executing the following sequence of instructions?
     
    mov al, -5
    xor ah, ah
    mov cl, 5
    div cl
    
    //a) -1
    //b) 255
    //c) 50
    //d) 0
    //e) 1
    //f) -50
```

I`ve compiled the code in visual studio using UASM and after the division the value of AX is 132h

Comment: Weird question, the upper 48 bits of RAX are not affected so we don't know the state

Comment: right answer is find a new school that is competent enough to teach.

Comment: Related: [How do AX, AH, AL map onto EAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15191178) .  I have to agree with old_timer here; RAX is two letters different from AL so it's not an easy typo, and this is a critical distinction in assembly.  As Jester says, the value in AX produced by the `div` (not dependent on initial conditions) isn't one of the options, so likely they did mean to ask about AL not RAX.  If `132h` had been an option, we could have guessed that they were assuming RAX=0 to start with without mentioning it (which would also be very bad.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer is: you can't tell. Because the code only changes the low 16 bits, the top 48 bits are whatever they were before the block and that is not specified.

Note that `div` is unsigned so you need to convert the `-5` to unsigned which is `251`. Dividing by `5` gives result `50`, remainder `1` (as you have determined yourself, that gives `132h` in `AX` because remainder goes into `AH` and quotient into `AL`). Since that is not one of the options offered, we must assume they really wanted the value of `AL` not `RAX` so I would pick `50`.