# Why does this code print different values compiled by clang and gcc?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

asm.s:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.global Foo
Foo:
    mov ax, 146
    ret
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int Foo(void);

int main(int argc, char** args){
    printf("Asm returned %d\n", Foo());
    return 0;
}
```

Now I compile and link:

```
(compiler name) -c asm.s -o asm.o
(compiler name) asm.o main.c -o  main
./main
```

I'm using Windows and the x64 windows binary of LLVM.

GCC prints 146 (as expected), but code produced by clang prints a random value, why? There are apparently some issues with debugging clang binaries with gdb on Windows, so I can't provide any gdb logs. The GCC binary is doing what I expect it to, but not Clang.

Comment: Probably GCC happens to call it with the high half of EAX already zero.  You told the compiler it returns an `int` (4 bytes in x86 and x86-64 calling conventions), but you only modified the low 16 bits, leaving existing garbage in the high 16.  The C equivalent is like `int retval;`  `memcpy(&retval, &tmp, 2)` except using registers.  See [How do AX, AH, AL map onto EAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15191178) - writing EAX zero-extends into RAX, but 8 and 16-bit partial registers are different.

Comment: On my computer, with gcc, I also get "random values". Well, not that random. Each value I get, is 146 modulo 65536. As expected when only the 16 lower bits (ax) has been set to 146, and the rest let to whatever there was.

Comment: In other words, you just got lucky to have 146 with one of the compiler. The only thing your code guarantees, is that it prints numbers `x` such has `x%65536` is 146. 146 is one of the possible outcome.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: `mov eax, 146` would be most appropriate, especially since the return type is `int` not `long long`.  But `mov eax, 146` does write the full RAX so is what compilers would do for `int64_t` or `uint64_t` as well.

Comment: The easiest way to figure out the right way to code it is to write a C version of `foo()` and look at the generated assembly.

Comment: @chrsig I call that the bad kind of lucky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `mov eax, 146` to match a return type of 32-bit or wider.

See *[How do AX, AH, AL map onto EAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15191178)* - writing EAX zero-extends into RAX, but 8 and 16-bit partial registers keep the legacy 386 behaviour of just merging, unfortunately.

You told the compiler it returns an `int` (4 bytes in x86 and x86-64 calling conventions), **but you only modified the low 16 bits of EAX/RAX, leaving existing garbage in the high 16 of the 32-bit `int` return value which the caller looks for in EAX.**

`sizeof(int) == 4` in all 32 and 64-bit calling conventions for x86 so it returns in EAX.
16-bit AX is a `short` or `unsigned short` in C.  (Or `int16_t` / `uint16_t`)

If you declared the return type as `short`, the caller would only look in AX, ignoring high garbage as required by the calling convention for narrow return values ([unlike for args narrower than 32-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706721/is-a-sign-or-zero-extension-required-when-adding-a-32bit-offset-to-a-pointer-for/36760539#36760539), as an unwritten extension to at least x86-64 System V, maybe also Windows x64, which clang depends on).

**See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output) for how to look at compiler-generated code to see correct asm for functions like this.**

---

**The low 16 bits of your return value are `146`**.  You can see this if you look at it in hex, e.g. `xxxx0092`.

Probably GCC happens to call it with the high half of EAX already zero, clang doesn't.  With different code in the caller, GCC might have used RAX for a non-small value as well.  It's just luck for the C caller and optimization options you happened to test with.

The C equivalent is `int retval;`  `memcpy(&retval, &tmp, 2)` except using registers, not replacing the uninitialized garbage in the high half of `retval`.