# Does BX have the same value as EBX im x86?

Tags: assembly, x86

Lets say we have this code below where val1, val2, and sum are 32 bits and BX is the BX register.

```
sum = (val1 + BX) - val2
```

When writing the code and using the BX register can we use `EBX` directly instead of using `movzx EBX, BX`?

Comment: Did you take a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture?

Comment: Using `movzx` like this suggests that it's promoting a 16bit value to a 32 bit value.  Are you sure val1, val2 and sum are all 32bits?

Comment: If the high 16 bits of EBX are *already* zero, then there would be no need to zero them again with `movzx`. So, maybe? It depends on the context.

Comment: Assuming `val1` and `val2` are 32 bit registers, there are no instructions that do mixed addition/subtraction between 16 and 32 bit. You have to use EBX. Regarding the relationship between EBX and BX, refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191178/how-do-ax-ah-al-map-onto-eax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is no.

`BX` is 16-bit value and `EBX` is 32-value.  While they can represent the same number, there's no requirement that they do.  Storing into BX doesn't modify the full `EBX`, so if you don't know how `BX` got its value, you cannot assume `EBX` holds the same number — we only know for sure that just the low 16 bits are the same.

Note that when mixing data sizes, you need to be fully aware of sign!  For example, let's take the 16-bit number 0xffff.  If this number is meant to be understood as signed, then the 32-bit equivalent is 0xffff ffff (e.g. -1<sub>10</sub>).  Whereas if this number 0xffff is meant to be understood as unsigned, then the 32-bit equivalent is 0x0000 ffff (e.g. 65535<sub>10</sub>).

The instruction `movzx` zero extends so as to assume the original `BX` value as unsigned.  While the instruction `movsx` would be used if we assume the original `BX` value is signed.  After one of those instructions, the numeric value in `BX` and `EBX` will be the same number, if you knew and applied the proper signed-ness.

If you don't know the signed'ness of `BX`, then the problem is ambiguous.

The way we usually find out the signed'ness of a value is to be told — typically by a programmer, via a variable declaration using a data type in C or other language.  The type of the variables are remembered and translated by a compiler into appropriate instructions such as `movsx` and `movzx`, when needed to extend a 16-bit value for participation in 32-bit arithmetic.  So, a programmer makes a program, which informs the compiler what to do.  In case of a snippet like you're showing there's missing information (e.g. type declarations) that a compiler (or assembly programmer) would have were it complete and compile-able.

(You also have to consider whether you are allowed to modify `EBX`, I would think that usually in the context of a code snippet, the answer would be yes, here since `BX` already has a value of interest.  But, to be clear you could send the extended value to another register, such as `movzx EAX, BX` — don't have to sign/zero extend into the same register.)

Comment: Fun fact: for zero-extending 8-bit to 32-bit, movzx to a different register is more efficient on Intel CPUs: it can benefit from [mov-elimination for zero latency and no back-end uop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all).  So *prefer* `movzx eax, bl` if possible.  Doesn't matter for `movsx ebx, bl` vs. `movsx eax, bl` (an execution unit is needed for the data-dependent high bits when sign extending), or for 16 bit register sources on current CPUs.  Prefer working with 32-bit values in the first place, like movzx/sx loads.