# Why do the AL, BL, and CL registers behave weird?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, cpu-registers

```
section .data
    format db '%d', 0x0a, 0

section .text
    global ft_strlen

ft_strlen:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov ecx, [ebp + 8]
    mov eax, 0
    
    loop:
    mov cl, [ecx + eax]
    inc eax
    cmp cl, 0
    jne loop

    mov esp, ebp 
    pop ebp
    ret
```

When I use the CL register the program works properly but when I use AL it gives me an infinite loop. And when I use BL it gives me a SEGV.
Actually it's so weird because three of them are 8-bit registers.

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger. Look closely at what happens to ecx after the `mov cl, [ecx + eax]`

Comment: Even though your code some how shows what you mean, it does not show how do you call ```ft_strlen``` and how you do pass arguments to it and even worse, it does not represent if you had already ```push``` ed ```eax```, ```ebx```, and ```ecx``` registers before and ```pop```ed them afterwards or not. How do you use ```mov cl, [ecx + eax]``` in a loop while you modified ```ecx```? The same doubt applies also for ```eax``` and ```ebx```. Try to use for instance ```dl``` to make sure your code run properly and TRY TO DEBUG IT.

Comment: [How do AX, AH, AL map onto EAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15191178) , and EBX is call-preserved so the caller is likely depending on it not changing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I use `cl` register the program works properly but when I use `al` it gives me an infinite loop

Both options are equally wrong but the effect they have is mostly coincidential!

In `mov cl, [ecx + eax]`, ECX is the base address of the string and EAX is the offset into the string. You should not be loading the byte from the string into CL since CL is the lowest 8 bits of the larger ECX register, and similarly you should not be loading the byte into AL since AL is the lowest 8 bits of the larger EAX register.

> and when I use `bl` it gives me a SEGV.

Using BL only becomes an option, once you preserve its pre-existing value (on the stack). That's because EBX is "[call-preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268586/what-are-callee-and-caller-saved-registers/56178078#56178078)" in the standard calling conventions.  Compiler-generated code calling your function will assume EBX still has the same value after their `call`.  Your options are to save/restore EBX somewhere, or not modify it or any parts of it.

If you use a debugger to see where the segfault happens, for this case you should see it happening somewhere after your function returns.  This is typically a sign you've violated the calling convention somehow, stepping on your caller's toes.  The other two bugs, AL or CL, are likely producing crashes in your own function where you can see the bad address.

> actually it's so weird because three of them are 8bit registers.

The x86 architecture has no separate 8-bit registers. What we perceive as 8-bit registers is always part of a larger register.  See *[How do AX, AH, AL map onto EAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191178/how-do-ax-ah-al-map-onto-eax)* for the details, which apply equally to AL, BL, CL, and DL.

### Solution: Use another call-clobbered register like EDX

```
ft_strlen:
  mov   ecx, [esp+4]          ; Base
  xor   eax, eax              ; Offset
.loop:
  movzx edx, byte [ecx + eax]
  inc   eax
  test  dl, dl
  jnz   .loop
  dec   eax                   ; Don't include zero-terminator
  ret
```

Your code was including the zero-terminator in the returned count. Usually we don't do that.

If you want to know how much space to allocate for a copy, that would save you the trouble of adding `1` to the return value.  But give the function a different name to avoid confusion with the C standard library `strlen` function which doesn't include the terminator.  And be sure to document in comments any ways your function is different from standard functions that do similar things, when you're doing it intentionally.  If this was unintentional, just change the code to make it an implementation of C's `strlen`.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I wasn't know that al and ah are two halfs of ax, I thought they are just other 8-bit registers.
thank you so much for your effort.