# Assembly x86, mov $constant, %register

Tags: assembly, x86

I have the following code snippet:

```
mov $0, %eax
mov $0x2023, %ax
mov $1, %ah
```

What happens when `mov $0x2023, %ax` is executed?

I expected %eax=0x20231 but it is 0x123. I've used a debugger and saw that %ax was 0x2023, but %ah becomes 20 and %al becomes 23. Why does this happen? Below is how I thought the code will run.

```
mov $0, %eax # eax = (AX)0000000000000000  (AH)00000000  (AL)00000000
mov $0x2023, %ax # eax = (AX)0010 0000 0010 0011  (AH)00000000  (AL)00000000
mov $1, %ah # eax = (AX)0010 0000 0010 0011  (AH)00000001  (AL)00000000
```

Comment: If partial registers had mapped into EAX the way you thought (or by using `or $0x2023<<16, %eax`), the final value would be `0x20230100` for the bit-pattern represented in base-2 in your last code block.  Place-value matters; you can't collapse or omit zeros when they're between or below any significant bits, only leading zeros can be omitted without changing the value when writing a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EAX is not composed of AX, AH, and AL the way you think!

See [How do AX, AH, AL map onto EAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191178/how-do-ax-ah-al-map-onto-eax)

```
                     high end     low end
                     |            |
                     v            v 
                     <---  EAX --->
mov $0, %eax         00  00  00  00 

                             <-AX->
mov $0x2023, %ax     00  00  20  23

                             AH  AL
mov $1, %ah          00  00  01  23
                     <-??->
```

No name was given to the ?? part that runs from bit 16 to bit 31.
Personally, I regularly call it AXE.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifications. Now I've understood how it works.