# Seeking for the the method for adding the DL (data register) value to DX register

Tags: x86, virtualbox, nasm, bootloader, osdev

I had something in my mind to spice up the code that draw the pixels on the screen about what if I can make a condition that change the ***variable*** (dl register/data stack) value by 1, 2 and 5, then make the code to increase/decrease value by ***variable***.

```
add dx, dl ; something like that, the assembler gave me an error: incorrect/illegal combination of opcodes and operands
```

Here's the full code, modified by me (OG code from the [video](https://youtu.be/HmoSg5p-AXc?si=Q9T06AqFtxSH1kn8)):

```
bits 16
org 0x7c00

start:
cli
push 0x0A000
pop es
xor di, di
xor ax, ax
mov ax, 0x13
int 0x10
jmp payload

payload:
add dl, 1
cmp dl, 3
jg condition
mov ah, 0x0c
add al, 1
mov bh, 0x00
add cx, 1
add dx, [dl] ; from reference, the assembler said: invalid 16-bit effective address
int 0x10
jmp payload

condition:
mov dl, 0
jmp payload

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Waiting for your answers and feedback.

P.S. For those who are confused, I'll rephrase the code part I want to add in a C syntax *(may be some inaccuracies, you can always fix me)*:

```
byte reg1;
byte reg2 = 1;

int main() {
  reg1 += &reg2;

  if (reg2 == 1) {
    reg2 = 2;
  } else if (reg2 == 2) {
    reg2 = 5;
  } else if (reg2 == 5) {
    reg2 = 1;
  };

  return 0;
}
```

**As for my config: I compile the code into .img (floppy disk) file.**

I tried to figure out what's wrong and fixed the question to be more understandable. I asked my question because I want to follow the DRY (Don't
Repeat Yourself) coding principle to reduce the CPU overhead if there's no use to apply the dl register, then I could use the other unit that can hold the value compatible with DX, otherwise, give me a verdict if that's possible or not.

Thank you.

Comment: x86 doesn't have instructions that allow adding 8-bit and 16-bit registers. That is the reason for your error.

Comment: DL is the low half of DX.  `add dl,dl` / `adc dh, 0` would work to add DL zero-extended to 16-bit (so the top half is the immediate `0` for ADC).  But IDK why you'd want to do that, doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Since this is a botoloader DL will originally have the value of the boot disk. You don't seem to initialize DX at all with an appropriate starting value. To me it is unclear what you are really trying to achieve.

Comment: You can't use an 8-bit register as part of a memory operand. It still isn't clear to me with your C code what you are trying to do.

Comment: It appears you may still not understand that DL is actually part of the DX register. DL is the lower 8 bits of DX and DH is the upper 8 bits of DX. Changing DL or DH changes DX. Changes DX will potentially alter DH and DL. They aren't independent registers.

Comment: See [How do AX, AH, AL map onto EAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15191178) for more details about how 8-bit registers like DL and DH are part of 16-bit registers like DX.  Your C seems unrelated to the asm instruction you're asking about; the variables in your C are all `byte`, but you're using asking about the 16-bit register DX.

Comment: That's just the high-level representation, then you'd better say how I supposed to stack both 8-bit registers to get the 16-bit value, or perhaps to use the data stack to do so.